# Parsing JSON nested array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, frontend

I have an API that returns the following JSON values as string.

```
"[
    ["West Baton Rouge test hello world", "1"],
    ["LSU Parking \u0026 Transportation Services", "2"],
    ["demokljafsk", "3"],
    ["latest", "19"],
    ["Hello check", "20"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "21"],
    ["World", "22"],
    ["altered value.", "23"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "24"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "25"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "26"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "27"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "28"],
    ["Rocking Client", "29"],
    ["West Baton Rouge", "30"],
    ["Test Client", "31"]
]"
```

I am having hard time trying to get the first value of each array with JQuery and log it into console with following code.

```
  $.get("/controller", function (data) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
        for (var eachdata in data) {
            console.log(eachdata[0]);
        }
   });
```

I am new to JQUERY and wonder what is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) for Arrays

```js
var data = [
    ["West Baton Rouge test hello world", "1"],
    ["LSU Parking \u0026 Transportation Services", "2"],
    ["demokljafsk", "3"],
    ["latest", "19"],
    ["Hello check", "20"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "21"],
    ["World", "22"],
    ["altered value.", "23"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "24"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "25"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "26"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "27"],
    ["Dinesh Devkota", "28"],
    ["Rocking Client", "29"],
    ["West Baton Rouge", "30"],
    ["Test Client", "31"]
];

for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
   console.log(data[i][0]);
}

// with jQuery
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
   console.log(value[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get("/controller", function (data) {
    console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
    for (var eachdata in data) {
        console.log(data[eachdata][0]);
    }
});
```

The problem is `for-in` returns keys, not values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i][0]);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5db2h32g/1/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery `$.each` is a very helpful utlity:

```
$.each( data, function( arrayIndex, arrayElement) {
    console.log(arrayElement[0]);
});
```

When it is used on array, the first argument of callback is the index, second argument is the array element.

it also creates a closure which can be very helpful when processing asynchronous code within loops

Reference [jQuery.each() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)